# Nextjs always showing the root not-found.tsx page, instead of the matched nested page

Tags: next.js, next.js13

my app folder structure is like this:

```
app/
  [lang]/
    dashboard/
      -not-found.tsx           // nested 404 page
      status-and-balance/
        page.tsx
  -not-found.tsx               // root 404 page
```

for the url `/en/dashboard/users` , with doesn't exist, the app is displays the root 404 page, instead of the nested one. And this is of course wrong behavior.

someone knows why it happens?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching, I found [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48763)

basically this feature isn't exist yet, but there is a [workaround](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48763#issuecomment-1623745516). copping the answer here:

```
/[lang]/dashboard/[...notFound]/page.js
```

Then inside page.js have a method call:

```
export default function NotFoundCatchAllPage() { notFound(); }
```

This will then trigger the segment's not-found.js instead of the default root one.